# Camera RAW image processing with Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, directx, sharpdx, writeablebitmap

I want to create a Windows Store app in C# to process to camera RAW images. It looks like I can load the RAW images using Microsoft's Windows Imaging Component (WIC), but when then I want to manipulate the images in a Windows Store app, I run into a problem.

To manipulate images in Windows Store apps, the primary option I found is using a WriteableBitmap object, but WriteableBitmap objects have only 8 bits per channel. Most DSLRs, including mine, have 14 bits per channel. I don't want to lose that much color depth. I suppose I could go the DirectX approach, but I'd rather not have to deal with C++ for this project. There's SharpDX, which lacks a bit in documentation, but I'd tackle it anyway if it's the best choice. Are there other ideas?

So what are the options, and which solution would you favor in my position? How can I load RAW images into a Windows Store application and make changes to those images without losing color depth?

Comment: This was asked over a year ago, did you find a solution?